# mysql/apache/php over windows 10 or over dockers for windows

Tags: mysql, php, docker, apache2, windows-10

I would like to know what would be more efficient (speed and memory mainly), run apache/php/mysql windows 10 versions over windows 10 or also under windows 10 run apache, php and mysql dockers.

I will run it over a xeon 12/24 cpus with 32gb

Is there any comparative?

The use will be very intensive, and we manage huge ammount of data in mysql database.

thanks in advance

Comment: On Windows? None of these packages were designed for Windows and might not work as well as on a more native platform such as Linux.

Comment: thats not the question

Comment: I didn't post that as an answer because it isn't one. It is, however, something you need to consider as part of your performance evaluation.

Comment: i use the box for other stuff and it is powerfull enough for handle all

Comment: I just want to see what option is better, native windows 10 apps or dockers

Comment: Dockers is another level of complexity (overhead), if you want to go there,  Your choice.